# C# - how to get cpu, memory and disk usage in % as seen in task manager

Tags: c#-4.0

Those parameters can be seen in a Task Manager.

[image]

Comment: Have you fond an answer to this ? If NO, i am willing to answer it as it seems very very easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer maybe a bit huge but it will answer the entire question except for the **DISK USAGE** part.

**Getting the CPU utilization in percentage(%)**

Not sure if `WMI` can be used for this case but i prefer not to use `WMI` because not all the machines support `WMI`.I will try to use other classes such as `PerformanceCounter` or so for the solutions.Here's a sample code that will return the CPU utilization in **%**

```
public FinalResult as float;
public async void GetCPUCounter()
{
CounterSample firstValue = cpuCounter.NextSample();
await Task.Delay(900); //delay is required because first  call will always return 0
CounterSample secondValue = cpuCounter.NextSample();
FinalResult = CounterSample.Calculate(firstValue, secondValue);
await Task.Delay(900);
GetCPUCounter(); //calling again to get repeated values
}
```

Now, just use a `Windows.Forms.Timer` to repeatedly get the cpu utilization.Before that, just call `GetCPUCounter()` once from anywhere in your code, let's say from `Form_load` event  :

```
 private void Form_load(...)
 {
  GetCPUCounter();
 }
 private void mytimer_Tick(....)
 {
  string cpuUsage =  finalresult.ToString() + "%"
 }
```

**Getting the memory utilization in percentage(%)**

Here's a full class with 2 `async` methods that will return both memory usage and total memory:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;

public class Memory
{
public int TotalRamInMb;
public int TotalRamInGb;
public double UsedRam;
public int UsedRamPercentage;
public string GetTotalRam()
{
    var CI = new ComputerInfo();
    var mem = ulong.Parse(CI.TotalPhysicalMemory.ToString());
    int Mb = Convert.ToInt16(mem / (double)(1024 * 1024));
    TotalRamInMb = Mb;
    if (Mb.ToString().Length <= 3)
        return Mb.ToString() + " MB physical memory";
    else
    {
        return (Convert.ToInt16(Mb / (double)1024)).ToString() + " GB physical memory";
        TotalRamInGb = Convert.ToInt16(Mb / (double)1024);
    }
}
public async void GetUsedRam()
{
    double URam;
    Process[] allProc = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (var proc in allProc)
        URam += ((proc.PrivateMemorySize64) / (double)(1024 * 1024));
    UsedRam = URam;
    UsedRamPercentage = (UsedRam * 100) / TotalRamInMb;
    await Task.Delay(900);
    GetUsedRam();
}
}
```

Get the values from the variables such as `UsedRam`, `UsedRamPercentage`,`TotalRamInMb` and so... And make sure to call `GetUsedRam()` once like we did with `GetCPUCounter` and then use a `Forms.Timer` to repeatedly get the values from the above variables.

I will update the answer soon by adding *Disk usage retrieval process* . Cheers!